# Mapping in .net4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

while going through video tutorials for mvc2 which i downloaded from microsoft's website, the traineer said that there is facility available in .net4 that we can map the fields of two object of different class and we need not to set there values one by one.

let say i have got a table named tblusermaster which contains 20 columns and i have created a model named usermasterModel which also contains almost same kind of fields and name.

so when i wants to assign values from object of tblusermaster  to object of usermasterModel i will have to set value for all 20 fields manually one by one but he was saying that there is a facility to map such thing and we will not have to write 20 lines to transfer values from one object to another (of different class but same type and name).

i have done google for this but not able to get answer that how to do that.

please help me out and give me link and any good tutorial for this.

Thanks
EDIT: its on http://www.asp.net/mvc  video names are asp.net mvc2 basic and another one is asp.net mvc2 ninja black belt by Scott Hanselman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably referring to the **[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)** project on CodePlex.

There is a screencast on it [here](http://www.itscreencast.com/language/dotnet/introduction-to-automapper/1853).

Comment: your link is really very good and helpfull but he (traineer) said that its new feature added in .net 4

Comment: why don't you just skim through the video and find the spot where he mentions it? (then if you still are unsure, let me know the time in the video which he mentions it and ill takea look)